# ZK BindComposer value set programmatically not applied while retrieving

Tags: binding, refresh, zk

I am using zk BindComposer for form binding. I have a combobox to which I set value programmatically . When I retrieve the value it's null. How to refreshing programmatically set value while using bindcomposer?

```
<div apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" 
    viewModel="@id('vm') @init('in_raster_hms.formCtrl.patient.PatientViewModel')"form="@id('patient') @load(vm.patient) ">
    <combobox id="comboCity" selectedItem="@bind(patient.city)" ></combobox>
```

Controller:

```
comboCity.setSelectedIndex(2);
```

I set selected item programmatically. When I retrieve patient object from binder the value of comboCity is null. I think the combobox selection to be reload.

If I choose from combo manually it works fine.

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: i added the sample code in question

Comment: Ok, your mixing some concepts here. The encountered behavior is normal. Please explain __what__ you want to do and __why__ you want to do it, not __how__ you want to do it. Why do you use form-binding?